# Why does flood ping to localhost result in lower RTT's?

Tags: networking, performance, ping

I used `ping` to do an estimate of lower bound for HTTP request times as part of a feasibility study.

In order to make the test faster I lowered the interval of the ping (to get enough pings to get a reasonable average) and noted that if the interval gets short the RTT against local host dropped. For example:

```
>sudo ping -i 0.01 -c500 -q localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- localhost ping statistics ---
500 packets transmitted, 500 received, 0% packet loss, time 5986ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.006/0.007/0.055/0.004 ms
>sudo ping -i 0.00 -c500 -q localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- localhost ping statistics ---
500 packets transmitted, 500 received, 0% packet loss, time 8ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.003/0.004/0.016/0.000 ms, ipg/ewma 0.018/0.004 ms
```

(using actual `-f` option yielded similar results as `-i 0.00`).

Why does the flood `ping` give 4us RTT while the non-flood gives 8us? If I skip the `-q` flag it gets even worse as the non-flood will get up to 34us. Why this difference for printing a line for each individual pings?

My guess is that the ICMP packets are put in a queue and there's a latency before the kernel processes the queue and if there's more ICMP packets it could be that it can process them all in the same go.

A follow up question might be if ping RTT's are relevant for local host, it might be that TCP/IP is not being used when doing a localhost HTTP request.

For the record: I'm running Linux (#1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u2).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what kind of CPU you are using, for me `-i 0.01` yields 45µs rtt, vs. 8µs with `-f`. This difference is (for my SandyBridge CPU) roughly consistent with the time needed for a wakeup from C6 power saving state:

http://ena-hpc.org/2014/pdf/paper_06.pdf

And yes, printing to the console can be quite expensive, depending on your terminal emulator (or ssh, etc.).

Comment: Perhaps printing to the console is expensive, but considering that the command lines are in quiet mode (nothing printed while pinging) I think one could rule that one out. Also I don't see why the wakeup time would be relevant - the RTT is the time between the ping is issued and the response is returned, I don't see why the CPU would enter power saving state here.